# Retrieving color information from ColorPickerDialog.java

Tags: java, android, color-picker

I'm currently using the ColorPickerDialog.java provided by Google. I can get it to load properly, and I can successfully choose a color, press the middle circle to confirm, and it will store it's information properly.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/ColorPickerDialog.html

Since the dialog uses Canvas to draw its elements and the Paint class to color everything, is there a way to retrieve the RGB float value from the selection? I don't know if it's simple and I'm just missing it, but I'm not fully acquainted with Android yet.

If it helps to visualize what I'm trying to achieve, I'm using the ColorPickerDialog.java to let the user select a color, and I want to use that color to tint some things in OpenGL (so I need float r, float g, float b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class can handle these conversions. The integer you are handed back is a bitwise version usually encoded as ARGB but there are functions to split it up.

```
import android.graphics.Color;

public class ColorComponents implements OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(int color) {
        final int red = Color.red(color);
        final int green = Color.green(color);
        final int blue = Color.blue(color);
    }
}
```